# Use different sizes of antD Modal

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I'm using antD modal to show an editor, the popup window should be fixed size to prevent size changing when collapsing/expanding sections inside.

So I customized:

```
.ant-modal-content {
max-height: 700px;
height: 700px;
width: 1000px;
/*overflow-y: auto;*/
/*overflow-x: auto;*/
```

}

but it's affecting other popups! 
I tried using `style={{height: '700px', width: '1000px'}}` of that specific modal but it didn't take affect.

How can I control the size of only one modal?

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-ci559?file=/index.css

(try to change the size o the syntax textarea as example for changing the size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS styles defined in `index.css` file are global styles, meaning they affect every element/component in each file.

If you want to apply some styles on a specific element/component, you have 2 options:

1. use [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet). They allow you to restrict styles to specific component and reuse class names without worrying about name clashes or css styles affecting other components or element.
2. As your popup window is a `div` element with a class named `wrapper`, apply the styles on `wrapper` class in `RuleEditor.css` file

   ```
    .wrapper {
      max-height: 400px;
    }
   ```

but keep in mind that if you use wrapper class somewhere else, these styles will affect those components/elements as well.

you also have to prevent `textarea` from resizing as well otherwise it will overflow. To do this, inside `RuleEditor.js` file, change the styles applied on `TextArea` component from

```
style={{ width: "100%", resize: "auto" }}
```

to

```
style={{ width: "100%", resize: "none" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix and auto width of your antd modal with

```
<Modal title={} open={open} width={1000} width="auto" closable={false} footer={null}></Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass directly width and height as props to Ant design modal like this

```
<Modal centered title="" footer={null} open={isModalOpen} onCancel={handleCancel} width={'360px'} height={'260px'}>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).